# How to handle missing values in linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, missing-data

I have a data frame with 60 variables and all variables have missing values in a way that none of the lines are complete:

```
complete.cases(data)
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [28] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [55] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [82] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[109] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[136] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So I guess I cannot use linear regression to impute missing values. Any idea how I can handle them so that I can perform my linear regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling missing values may include:

1. It's the best to omit variables for which most observations are missing.
2. Omitting the rows/observations/cases with missing values. This strategy is referenced as listwise deletion or complete case analysis. This is a possibility, if the type of missingness is MCAR (Missing Completely At Random), and there are still large enough sample after the deletions.
3. Different imputation techniques: mean/median/mode substitution, regression inputation, expectation-maximization (EM), multiple inputation, etc.